# Java 6: Constructor argument, null and the ternary operator

Tags: java, null, ternary-operator, java-6

Just for curiousity...

Assume I have a Class with two constructors:

```
public Class(){}
public Class(int x){}
```

and I want to create a new class through with the following statement below:

```
 new Class( ( true ) ? 100 : null);
```

Would this be acceptable? Will null instantiate the Class with the empty/default constructor? If not, is there a way to accomplish this with the ternary operator?

Note that I am on Java version 6.

Comment: Are you asking whether `mew Class()` is the same as new `Class(null)`?

Comment: Which package is `Class` name?

Comment: Hmm I don't think so. I think the answer to that is that () is not the same as null and that null in my example would actually call the Class(int) constructor. Right...?

Comment: Your code will be treated as `constructor with parameter` call.

Comment: It seems you answered your own question.

Comment: @PM: Well, not really! The question was if there's a workaround for this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do this

```
Class cl = flag ? new Class(100) : new Class();
```

By definition, the type of a `? :` is the same as the last argument. i.e. Object, you cannot make it type less and value less.

Comment: This is what I currently got actually, so there's no way to do this without assigning it with "Class c1 = ..."? :(

Comment: If you don't need to keep the object, I would avoid creating it in the first place.

Answer (score 2):

```
new Class( ( true ) ? 100 : null);
```

the reason you wont have an empty constructor is because, the only choices we would get would be `new Class(100)` and `new Class(null)`

```
1. new Class(null) 
2. new Class()
```

Now 1 is not same as 2

null is comprehended as an `Object`, where as the constructor is expecting a `int`. If we had

```
 public Class(Integer x){}
```

then `new Class(null)` would have been allowed since Object is a super class for Integer. Thus the only alternative is

```
boolean check = true;
check ? new Class(100) : new Class();
```

Comment: Thanks, this really refreshed my memory a lot! However... the last line (pretty much the answer to the actual question) is similar to Peter's answer (which was posted first)

Comment: As i said, it is the only answer :)

Comment: Yup, I just wanted to post my motivation for chosing Peter's answer as the "accepted" answer to the question but I really did appreciate the post though since I refreshed my memory about Integer/int, (void) and so on!

Comment: BTW `(void)` is not valid in Java.

Answer (score 0):

You can use variable arguments

```
Class(int... x){} //constructor
```

and then use `new Class();` or `new Class(2);`

Comment: class Class1{
   
  void doSomething(){
   new Class1();
   new Class1(2);
  }
   
   Class1(int... x){}
  }

Comment: Try to **compile** your code. `int... x;` is equivalent of `int[] x;` assuming that constructor with a parameter actually **uses** this parameter.

Comment: You can always check if(x!=null && x.length == 1) in the constructor and yes - I did compile my code, did you?  And moreover the OP wanted a way to know to use  new Class( ( true ) ? 100 : null); with a single constructor and using var args solves the purpose

Comment: Yes I did and got compilation error. I do not believe OP wanted `array` as a constructor parameter anyway.

Comment: @PM77-1 - From doc - The three periods after the final parameter's type indicate that the final argument may be passed as an array or as a sequence of arguments. So all though the data structure is array you can use it to pass just a single argument too which is what is required here

Comment: Assuming that this constructor updates class variable `i`, what should be the **type** of `i`?

Comment: Type will be array, but the question was not based on type, it was based on concept of being able to use single constructor with different arguments and var args fits the bill here

Comment: OK. Let's agree to disagree and stop the discussion.